# Can all tag numbers be extracted from a given protobuf serialization?

Tags: java, python, google-api, protocol-buffers

Given a protobuf serialization is it possible to get a list of all tag numbers that are in the message? Generally is it possible to view the structure of the message without the defining .proto files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most APIs will indeed have some form of reader-based API that allows you to enumerate a raw protobuf stream. However, that by itself is not enough to fully understand the data, since *without the schema* the interpretation is ambiguous:

- a varint could be zig-zag encoded (`sint32`/`sint64`), or not (`int32`/`int64`/`uint32`/`uint64`) - radically changing the meaning, or a boolean, or an enum
- a fixed-32/fixed-64 could be a signed or unsigned integer, or could be an IEEE754 float/double
- a length-prefixed chunk could be a UTF-8 string, a BLOB, a sub-message, or a "packed" repeated set of primitives; if it is a sub-message, you'll have to repeat recursively

So... yes and no. Certainly you can get the field numbers of the outermost message.

Another approach would be to use the *regular* API against a type with **no members** (`message Naked {}`), and then query the unexpected data (i.e. all of it) via the "extension" API that many implementations provide.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the tag numbers which appear in one particular message, but you won't get any nested messages - and you won't know the *types* of those fields, only some subset of possible types.

If you look at the [wire encoding](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html), you can see that (for example) byte arrays, strings and nested messages are all encoded the same way - so you may know that "field 3 is a length-prefixed binary field" but you won't know whether that means it's a nested message, a string or a byte array.